# How to find an object by a property from a List of List of objects in dart?

Tags: dart

Hello I am new to dart and trying to find an item by property name in a list of list.

```
class Product{
 String id;
 String title;
    Product(this.id,this.title);
}
void main(){
  
  List<List<Product>> allProdcuts=[
    //New Prodcuts
      [
          Product("1","Hammer"),
          Product("3","Nails"),
          Product("2","Screws"),
      ],
    futureItems,
    //Old Prodcuts
          [
          Product("4","Rock"),
          Product("5","Paper"),
          Product("6","Scissor"),
          ],
    //Rare Items
          [
          Product("7","Plank"),
          Product("8","Wires"),
          Product("9","Box"),
          ],
  ];
print(allProdcuts.where((itemsList)=>itemsList.contains((product)=>product.title='Wires')));  
//Returns ()


}
```

I have tried using for a single List:

```
  List<Product> futureItems=     [
          Product("101","Galactic Hammer"),
          Product("301","Galactic Nails"),
          Product("201","Galactic Screws"),
      ];
  print(newProduct.firstWhere((p)=>p.title=='Hammer'));
//Instance of 'Product'
```

Also tried this:

```
  print(allProdcuts.map((itemList)=>itemList.firstWhere((p)=>p.title=='Nails')));
// Bad state: No elementError: Bad state: No element.
```

But there is an element with the title='Nails'.I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `itemList.firstWhere((p)=>p.title=='Nails')` on each list, also the ones with no element with title `"Nails"`. Since `firstWhere` throws if there is no matching value, it does that for two of your three lists. Also, in the example, `itemsList.contains(...)` does not take a callback, so you are just checking whether a function is in the list, which it isn't. You might want to use `any` for that, but it won't solve the problem here.

To do this efficiently, I'd probably create helper function:

```dart
Product findByTitle(List<List<Product>> allProducts, String title) {
  for (var products in allProducts) {
    for (var product in products) {
      if (product.title == title) return product;
    }
  }
  // Or return `null`.
  throw ArgumentError.value(title, "title", "No element with that title");
}
```

The `return` in the middle allows you to skip out of the double iteration the moment you have a match, something which is harder to do with `firstWhere`/`map`/`forEach` etc.

One alternative solutions would be:

```dart
 var product = allProducts.expand((l) => l.where((p) => p.title == title)).first;
```

which finds *all* the products with the given title and flattens them into a single iterable, then picks the first one (if there are any). Because iterables are lazy, it will actually stop at the first match.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this.

One example is to use the [forEach()](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/Iterable/forEach.html) method:

```
allProdcuts.forEach(
    (List<Product> l)=>l.forEach(
                          (Product p){
                                      if (p.title=="Nails") 
                                          print(p.id);
                                     }
                                )
);
```

The for each method receives a function and applies this function to every element on the list. If you have a lists of lists, you can do this twice to get a function applied to each element of the sub lists.

The above code prints `3`, which is the desired result.

Another solution would be to flatten the list first, so you can have an easier search later.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(allProdcuts.any((innerListOfProducts) =>
  innerListOfProducts.any((product) => product.title == 'Wires')));
```

This code will return true if 'Wires' is in the inner list, and false otherwise.